# Sum with Integer object if not null

Tags: java, null, integer, drools

I do not know if it is possible in Java but I need a method to do a special "add function".
Let me explain,

SHORT VERSION:
Is it possible to add an int with an Integer object? I need a method to check if that integer object exists, and add 0 if the object is null, add the correct value otherwise
I tried

```
public static Integer isNull(Integer bonus){
    if (bonus == null)
        return Integer.valueOf(0);
    else
        return bonus;
}
```

but I can't enter the "null" branch.

FULL VERSION:
The Integer Bonus value is the result of a fired Drools rule. This rule return this Integer Bonus with the insertLogical(new object) statement. According the drools manual,

> insertLogical(new *Something*()); is similar to insert, but the object will
>   be automatically retracted when there are no more facts to support the truth
>   of the currently firing rule.
>   In other words, as soon as the condition of that rule is not true any more,
>   the Engine retracts the logically inserted fact. This is commonly referred
>   to as "truth maintenance"

So as long as the rule is valid the Bonus object exists and the normal sum is valid; but when the rules is retracted and the Bonus destroyed I need that sum to continue to be valid

In addiction, I can say I'm trying to implement the Magic The Gathering card game with Drools; so I'm trying to code cards like "when something, so something". With insertLogical I guessed I only have to care about the activation of the rule and not of its removal.

I hope my question is quite clear, and sorry for my bad English

BETTER EXPLANATION (maybe):
It is not so simple, the card has an Integer value, and sometimes, varying on the rules which are fired, this value can change. I don't want to manually change the value, because there can be many and many ways this value can change, so I need the insertLogical() to at lest don't care about changing again those values when the rule does not exists anymore.

EXAMPLE:
I have a card in play which as the value 3. Then I play another card which increase that value to 4, but only as long as this second card remains in play. 
Normally, with the Drools insert statement I have to write some code which increase the value field of that card (which is mapped into a Java Class) and then some code which decrease back that value when the second card is not in play anymore. With the insertLogical (if I understood it correctly) I have the decrease code for free.
The problem is inserteLogical only apply to new java Objects (not existings ones or most of all not to objects fields); so I declare a new Bonus object (a positive or negative Integer) I can add to card value, but it can be destroyed at any time and the "add" function must be still valid.

when the second card is played (or it is already and I play the first) I have to modify the first card value like this

```
card.value=card.value + isNull(bonus)
```

so it can automatically change if a bonus (the second card) exist or not

Comment: What do you mean you cant enter null branch? Working for me unless I misunderstand you

Comment: How about you give some examples of what you want to happen, something like: `assertEquals(0, isNull(null));` and `assertEquals(10, isNull(10));`

Comment: Answer for aryanaq:
I can't enter the null branch calling this static method from a Main, passing the Integer value in args[1]

Comment: Increasing the confusion? You can't pass an Integer in `args[x]`, if this is `static void main`'s (not `Main`'s) argument. - And: what "sum [needs] to continue to be valid?" I *think* I know what you are trying to do, but a clearer spec would help.

Comment: Uhhhhh, Yeah, a lot of confusion, 
I pass an Integer into 'args[0]' by parsing it like this 
_Integer.parseInt(args[0])_
AND is now clearer than before ?

Comment: It is more or less clear, because `Integer.parseInt` returns an int and not an Integer, so it can **never** return a null value. I suppose you catch the `NumberFormatException`, but have you got in the catch block ?

Comment: I was forced to use _args[0]_ and _Integer.parseInt()_ because I can't use Drools on my machine right now, but according to scheme that Integer should be created by a Drools fired rule.

Comment: Am I right if I say that what you want is first a way to convert an empty args[0] to null and second a way to treat that null as a true 0 to achieve compatibility with your future usage of Drools ?

Comment: Well, maybe that isn't the most elegant solution but it should work, so if it is possible please explain to me. thanks

Comment: The result of `Integer.parseInt(args[0])` is an `int`, and you can't replace `args[0]`, which is a `String`, with this result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have correctly understood what you want, here is an example of what you could do

```
/**
 * Take first value of a String [] as an Integer, and return null if not Ok
 * @param args a String[] that could come from main
 * @return integer value of args[0] or null
 */
private static Integer getArgs0(String[] args) {
    Integer bonus = null;
    if (args.length > 0) { // special case no args
        try {
            bonus = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e) {}
    }
    return bonus;
}

/**
 * Convert a null Integer to 0 - else leave it untouched
 * @param bonus input Integer
 * @return 0 if bonus is null else bonus
 */
private static int zeroIfNull(Integer bonus) {
    return (bonus == null) ? 0 : bonus;
}
```

Comment: The IDE say: _incompatible conditional operand types int and integer_

Comment: @Fjordo On what line is the error ? I tried it with Java 7 and Netbeans and had not even a warning ...

Answer (score 5):

With java 8 it can be:

```
public int zeroIfNull(Integer bonus) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(bonus).orElse(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I used following to sum two double num in null safe way. I welcome if there is any better way to do this though.

```
Double sum(Double num1, Double num2){
        if(Objects.isNull(num1) && Objects.isNull(num2)){
            return null;
        }
        return Double.sum(Optional.ofNullable(num1).orElse(0D),Optional.ofNullable(num2).orElse(0D));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's best, if you define a wrapper class for your Integer. If I understand right, the Integer represents the value of the card. Then define a class Card like this:

```
public class Card {
  private int value;
  private boolean active;
}
```

Now you can create a List and implement a method to sum.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I have added an example which can be useful for resolving the problem

Answer (score 0):

If a rule inserts an `Integer` object due to the existence of a card (or a combination of cards) in a hand (or on the table or...), and this bonus value needs to be accumulated in an overall bonus counter:

```
rule "add to bonus"
when
    $newBonus: Integer()
    $accumulated: AccumulatedBonus()
then
    modify( $accumulated ){ setValue( $accumulated.getValue() + $newBonus() ) }
    retract( $newBonus );
end
```

It does not matter how you insert the "new bonus". Once accumulated, it can be discarded. - Of course, the rules of the game may demand otherwise, but that's for OP to know.

`AccumulatedBonus` is a simple wrapper class for an int field `value`, required because you can't modify an Integer and they don't have an "identity" so you couldn't distinguish it from a "new" bonus due to a card (combination). Consider following F. Böller's advice and using different (!) wrapper classes for different integers that must be distinguished from each other.

Comment: I don't know how to Answer to you, I did not correctly understand drools code, I'm pretty novice with it, and most of all I have not clear how to explain the problem in English.
It is not the rule effect to add an Integer Object, but it has to modify an existing java value which represent a played card. Then I don't want to change back the value to his default when the rule is somehow retracted but I want the value automatically change. I don't know if it is possible.